Множественный UNPIVOT, возможен ли?
Имеется скрипт у которого на выходе одна строка с итогом и куча столбцов.
Необходимо развернуть столбцы по группам.
Пример выходных данных:

Пример того как должно получиться:

Получается только одна группа:
    SELECT * FROM(/*здесь большой скрипт*/  )tt
  UNPIVOT (
  gr FOR title IN(18_a,18_b)
  )unpvt

Как сделать разбиение по колонкам?

Судя по UNPIVOT мы имеем дело с SQL Server. Но неплохо было бы это указать явно. Заодно сразу возникает вопрос, насколько постоянны имена полей в выходном наборе, требующем трансформации.

Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.
Все в рамках вопроса как текст, без картинок.

Попробуйте следующие два решения для MS SQL Server.
Имена столбцов таблицы базы данных должны начинаться с букв.
SQL
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, начало
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (A_18 INT, A_19 int, B_18 INT, B_19 INT, C_18 INT, C_19 INT);
INSERT @tbl ( A_18, A_19, B_18, B_19, C_18, C_19) VALUES
( 20, 50, 20, 50, 32, 54);
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, конец

SELECT * FROM @tbl;

-- Метод #1
SELECT 18 AS Age, A_18 AS A, B_18 AS B, C_18 AS C
FROM @tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT 19, A_19, B_19, C_19
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY Age;

-- Метод #2
SELECT v.*
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
      (18, A_18, B_18, C_18),
      (19, A_19, B_19, C_19)
   ) AS v(Age, A, B, C)
ORDER BY v.Age;

Результат



Age
A
B
C




18
20
20
32


19
50
50
54



